# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' when provided blank input

Tags: python-2.7

I have below code gives me ValueError when input is left blank

```
U = find_lastuid()   # Return variable from other function
uidnum = int(raw_input("What is uid number? (default is: %s)" % U))
if not uidnum:
    print("defualt uid is used: %s" % uidnum)
else:
    print("UID is %s" % uidnum)


uidnum = int(raw_input("What is uid number? (default is: %s)" % U))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Can someone tell what is wrong with this code?
I can see similar code works in REPL

```
>>> id = 234
>>> a = raw_input("Enter id")
Enter id
>>> if not id:
...     print(id is blank)
... else:
...     print(id)
...
234
```

Comment: typo in first if statement's `raw_input`, and what is the value of U?

Comment: My bad, the if statement's `print` not `raw_input`

Comment: Please note that  U is type  int

Answer (score 1):

This is because you **cannot** convert an empty `string` to an `int`, what you could do, however is use a `try` and `except` block to handle this:

```
try:
    uidnum = int(raw_input("Enter uid:"))
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter a number!")
```

Comment: Thank YOU!  Skilledifire